# QGIS CadTools: changing parallel line fixed length from degrees to meters

Tags: qgis, parallel-lines

I'm new to QGIS and want to create a parallel line. I'm using the CadTools plugin to do so. When I add a parallel line, the fixed length is in degrees not meters. How do I change this so that the fixed length is in meters and not degrees.

Answer (score 3):

In order to change the units, you'll need to be working in a coordinate reference system that is in meters.

You can do this using [on the fly reprojection](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html#basic-fa-on-the-fly-reprojection) to one of your local coordinate systems that uses meters.